# Python: choosing indices from array that correspond to elements of specific value

Tags: python

I have an array that looks like this:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

I want to write a function that will randomly return some specified number of indices that correspond to a specified number. In other words, if I pass the function the array `x`, the desired number of indices such as `3`, and the target value `1`, I would want it to return an array such as:

`[0, 7, 13]`

Since `0`, `7`, and `13` are the indices that correspond to `1` in `x`.

Does anyone know how I might do this efficiently?

Comment: why `[0, 7, 13]` and not `[0, 1, 13]` (or another valid set of indices)? What have you tried so far that's not efficient? Seems like a simple loop should do the trick- did that not work for you?

Comment: I want it to be a random selection – sorry, the solution doesn't seem clear to me. Currently I do a random.choice and throw out the result if it's not of the desired value, which seems really inefficient

Comment: use enumerate to filter for the indices `[i for i, x in enumerate(x) if x == target_value]`, then make a random selection. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good to me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `random.sample` for this:

```
import random

def f(arr, target, num): 
    return random.sample([i for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x == target], k=num) 

x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]                                   
print(f(x, 1, 3))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sample function from the random module and pass it the list of indices that match the specified value:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]

from random import sample
def randomIndices(a,count,v):
    return sample([i for i,n in enumerate(a) if n==v],count)

print(randomIndices(x,3,1)) # [1,18,15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks how to do this efficiently, which depends on how you plan on using this code. As myself and others have pointed out, one way is to use `enumerate` to filter the list for the indices that correspond to the target value. The downside here is that each time  you pick a new target value or request a new sample, you have to once again `enumerate` the list which is an `O(n)` operation.

If you plan on taking multiple samples, you may be better off building a dictionary mapping the target value to the indices upfront. Then you can subsequently use this dictionary to draw random samples more efficiently than enumerating. (The magnitude of the savings would grow as `x` becomes very large).

First build the dictionary using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i, val in enumerate(x):
    d[val].append(i)

print(dict(d))
#{1: [0, 1, 7, 13, 15, 16, 18], 2: [2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17], 3: [3, 4, 9, 11]}
```

Now you can use `d` to draw your samples:

```
from random import sample

def get_random_sample(d, target_value, size):
    return sample(d[target_value], size)

print(get_random_sample(d, target_value=1, size=3))
#[16, 7, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next:

1. Get the indices of the items with value equal to 1
2. Use `random.sample` to select randomly only a few indices (without repetitions) extracted from the previous step.

Here is one way to do it (`n` indicates the number of indices to pick):

```py
from random import sample

x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
n = 3
target = 1

indices = frozenset(filter(lambda k: x[k] == target, range(len(x))))
out = sample(indices, min(len(indices), n))
print(out)
```

Note that the number of returned indices could be lower than `n` (if the number of 1s in the list is less than `n`)